# angular confirm, confirmIf tweaking

Tags: angularjs, confirm

I use angular and [angular-confirm](https://github.com/Schlogen/angular-confirm)

I made an interface with a list of buttons. 
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0465v52t3e

On each button there is a confirm like this :

```
<button ng-click="..." class="btn btn-lg btn-invisible" type="button"
        confirm="{{'Realy want to add it ?'|translate}}" >
    <span aria-hidden="false" class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
</button>
```

There is a lot of buttons in the list so if the user needs to click for example 10 of them, the confirm message will be boring after 2/3 times.

**QUESTION :**

Is there a way to display inside the confirm modal a button for "ok i understand, stop showing confirm" and on other button click confirm will not show.

It is on same idea that how modern web browser handle popup .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `$confirmModalDefaults` (to change confirm template and controller) and use `confirm-if`.

Or you can write your own confirm - https://github.com/Schlogen/angular-confirm/blob/master/angular-confirm.js is just ~100 rows.

Comment: i should learn to read ... the directive already include a parameter (`confirm-if`) to show or not the confirm :  `<button type="button" ng-click="delete()" confirm-if="checked" confirm="Are you sure, {{name}}?">Delete</button>`.

Answer (score 0):

The angular-confirm already include an attribut to show or hide the confirm message.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="delete()" confirm-if="checked" confirm="Are you sure, {{name}}?">Delete</button>
```

---

I made some modification on the plugin to add a message on "last time the confirm will show"

[image]

1) in the HTML the `confirm-last` attribut will show a warning text displayed on the confirm modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-invisible" type="button" ng-click="add(id)"
        confirm="add"
        confirm-if="showconfirm.add<=showconfirm.max"
        confirm-last="showconfirm.add==showconfirm.max" > 
    Add 
</button>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-invisible" type="button" ng-click="edit(id)"
        confirm="edit"
        confirm-if="showconfirm.edit<=showconfirm.max"
        confirm-last="showconfirm.edit==showconfirm.max" > 
    Add 
</button>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-invisible" type="button" ng-click="clone(id)"
        confirm="clone"
        confirm-if="showconfirm.clone<=showconfirm.max"
        confirm-last="showconfirm.clone==showconfirm.max" > 
    Add 
</button>
```

2) In the controller

```
$scope.showconfirm = {
    "max" : 2, // how much time the confirm will show for an action
    "add" : 0, // how many time it actually show the confirm for this action
    "edit" : 0,
    "clone": 0
} ;

 $scope.add = function(id) {
    $scope.showconfirm.add ++; 
    // ...
 }
 $scope.edit = function(id) {
    $scope.showconfirm.edit ++; 
    // ...
 }
```

3) change the default param of the module

```
angular.module('interfaceApp').run(function($confirmModalDefaults) {
    $confirmModalDefaults.templateUrl = "partials/elements/confirm.html";
    $confirmModalDefaults.defaultLabels.title = 'Confirmez';
    $confirmModalDefaults.defaultLabels.ok = 'Oui';
    $confirmModalDefaults.defaultLabels.cancel = 'Non';
    $confirmModalDefaults.defaultLabels.confirmLastMessage = "(Dernière confirmation pour cette action)";
});
```

4) create a html for the new template `confirm.html`

```
<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">{{data.title}}</h3></div>
<div class="modal-body">{{data.text}}</div>
<div class="modal-footer no-topbottom-padding">
    <div ng-show="data.confirmLast" style="float:left;padding: 10px;color:#FF0000">
        <i>{{data.confirmLastMessage}}</i>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;padding: 10px;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">{{data.ok}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">{{data.cancel}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

5) the edited module ( the edited part are marked with `**edited her**`):

```
/*
 * angular-confirm
 * https://github.com/Schlogen/angular-confirm
 * @version v1.2.4 - 2016-05-11
 * @license Apache
 */
(function (root, factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['angular'], factory);
    } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('angular'));
    } else {
        return factory(root.angular);
    }
}(this, function (angular) {
    angular.module('angular-confirm', ['ui.bootstrap.modal'])
        .controller('ConfirmModalController', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, data) {
            $scope.data = angular.copy(data);

            $scope.ok = function (closeMessage) {
                $uibModalInstance.close(closeMessage);
            };

            $scope.cancel = function (dismissMessage) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(dismissMessage)) {
                    dismissMessage = 'cancel';
                }
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss(dismissMessage);
            };

        })
        .value('$confirmModalDefaults', {
            template: '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">{{data.title}}</h3></div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body">{{data.text}}</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">{{data.ok}}</button>' +
            '<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">{{data.cancel}}</button>' +
            '</div>',
            controller: 'ConfirmModalController',
            defaultLabels: {
                title: 'Confirm',
                ok: 'OK',
                cancel: 'Cancel'
            }
        })
        .factory('$confirm', function ($uibModal, $confirmModalDefaults) {
            return function (data, settings) {
                var defaults = angular.copy($confirmModalDefaults);
                settings = angular.extend(defaults, (settings || {}));
                data = angular.extend({}, settings.defaultLabels, data || {});
                if ('templateUrl' in settings && 'template' in settings) {
                    delete settings.template;
                }
                settings.resolve = {
                    data: function () {
                        return data;
                    }
                };
                return $uibModal.open(settings).result;
            };
        })
        .directive('confirm', function ($confirm, $timeout) {
            return {
                priority: 1,
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    confirmIf: "=",
                    confirmLast: "=",  // **edited her**
                    ngClick: '&',
                    confirm: '@',
                    confirmSettings: "=",
                    confirmTitle: '@',
                    confirmOk: '@',
                    confirmCancel: '@'
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    function onSuccess() {
                        var rawEl = element[0];
                        if (["checkbox", "radio"].indexOf(rawEl.type) != -1) {
                            var model = element.data('$ngModelController');
                            if (model) {
                                model.$setViewValue(!rawEl.checked);
                                model.$render();
                            } else {
                                rawEl.checked = !rawEl.checked;
                            }
                        }
                        scope.ngClick();
                    }
                    element.unbind("click").bind("click", function ($event) {
                        $event.preventDefault();
                        $timeout(function() {
                            if (angular.isUndefined(scope.confirmIf) || scope.confirmIf) {
                                var data = {text: scope.confirm};
                                // **edited her**
                                if (scope.confirmLast) {
                                    data.confirmLast = scope.confirmLast;
                                }
                                if (scope.confirmTitle) {
                                    data.title = scope.confirmTitle;
                                }
                                if (scope.confirmOk) {
                                    data.ok = scope.confirmOk;
                                }
                                if (scope.confirmCancel) {
                                    data.cancel = scope.confirmCancel;
                                }
                                $confirm(data, scope.confirmSettings || {}).then(onSuccess);
                            } else {
                                scope.$apply(onSuccess);
                            }

                        });

                    });

                }
            }
        });
}));
```